# Writing in next column in csv file using c# and Unity

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

I need to write a .csv file, collecting data at runtime using Unity and C#. To doing so I write in every frame the data I need, but they are all written inside the first cell of the file.

The code that creates the file and writes the data is as follows:

```
//create the file that will record the player's position and actions over time
    void CreateFile()
    {
        //add to the path the name of the file with the date on which has been recorded
        filePath = path + "player" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + fileCounter + ".csv";

        //if the file already exists, then another recording has been done in the same day;  
        //increase the counter until there is no file with such path and create it
        while (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            fileCounter++;
            filePath = path + "player" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + fileCounter + ".csv";
        }

        //create the file at the current filePath
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            sw.WriteLine("time" + "," + "x_coord" + "," + "y_coord" + "," + "act");
        }
    }

    //append to the current player position file the position of the player
    void UpdateFile()
    { 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            var line = String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", playerLog.time, playerLog.x, playerLog.y, playerLog.action);
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Could please someone help me?

Comment: How do you open the CSV to verify? In case it is excell it sometimes uses `;` as the default separation symbol so you have to actively say somewhere that it should use`,` instead

Comment: Thanks! I used Excel to open them, and now using `;` instead of `,` it works